# У него поднялась высокая температура! Нельзя так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> **У него поднялась высокая температура!**

Только что услышала это по радио.
Так нельзя говорить, наверное? Ведь получается, что мы имеем изначально высокую температуру, которая начала подниматься и таки поднялась, а не нормальную температуру, которая стала подниматься, поднялась до высоких значений и поэтому стала высокой?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138050/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположение.

В словарях у слова "подняться" есть такое значение:
**Появиться, возникнуть.**
*Поднялся вопрос о платном образовании.

Поднялся ветер, буран.

Поднялась метель.

Прежние мысли, страхи, опасения поднялись в ком-либо.

Поднялись новые нарядные кварталы.

За месяц поднялся палаточный городок.*
*К вечеру поднялась метель, закрывая белыми хлопьями черные стекла.* Короленко, История моего современника.
*Ругань, женский плач и вой поднялись во всем вагоне.* Федин, Необыкновенное лето.

Ситуация похожа. Мне изначально казалось, что там значение "возникла". Может, примерно так и есть?

Comment: Вот это интересно!!!

Answer (score 1):

***У него поднялась высокая температура!***

1. **Семантика некорректная?** Есть немного...

А как по-другому сказать? У него поднялась температура до сорока градусов. А если без чисел, то никак не получится?

2. Поэтому **в разговорной речи**  грамматическое несоответствие часто не учитывается, а иногда такое сочетание можно встретить и на письме:

*При инфекционном заболевании у них **поднимается высокая температура**, а через три дня они уже на ногах и практически здоровы.* kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/высокая+температура

3. Как решить проблему? Можно считать, что это **фразеология**, и тогда никаких вопросов.

Или у кого-то есть **более интересное решение?**

Comment: Предложил же: *У него температура поднялась до высоких значений / высокой отметки!* Проще всего так: *У него высокая температура!* Вот это по-литературному. Фразеологизмом бы не назвал. Там ни одно слово не выкинешь.

Comment: Ваша фраза  из медицинской терминологии, а здесь обсуждается общеупотребительная речь. Еще варианты есть?

Comment: Не только. Так аристократы говорят.

Comment: Приведите пример светской аристократической беседы, пжста.

Comment: Мне делать нечего? Я не писатель.

Comment: А откуда про аристократов знаете?   Их же у нас нет.

Comment: Из фильмов.....

Comment: Так это когда было! А мы современность обсуждаем.

Comment: Высококультурные люди, которые ходят в театр, тоже так скажут.

Comment: Нет, если они высококультурные.  Это будет стилистическая неточность, необоснованное употребление  книжной речи в несоответствующей ситуации.

Comment: Нормальная это речь. Играет роль не ситуация, а окружение.

Comment: Интересное мнение, хотя и спорное. Ну да ладно, говорите так. Если в театр придете.

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, не стыкуется по смыслу.

Но если что-то неправильное очень часто используется, то оно становится правильным. Так устроена лингвистика. В данном случае оно стало выражением (не фразеологизмом). Но идеальным точно не станет.

Так что, если хотите, чтоб речь была идеальной, скажите как-то по-другому. Наверно, лучшим вариантом будет пропуск "поднялась". Но так говорить можно ввиду того, что это выражение очень часто используется и у всех на слуху.

Comment: Sharon написала, что если считать это фразеологией, то тогда никаких вопросов. Вы считаете, что это не фразеологизм, а устоявшееся выражение. Почему нельзя считать это фразеологизмом?

Comment: Потому что фразеологизмы неделимые, ни одно слово нельзя убрать.